# Temporarily daisy chaining meter pans

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm currently getting my electrical service upgraded from 200A to 320 (400A) service.  I'm doing preparation work for it -- I mounted the new meter pan along with two 200A panels.  I'd like to pre-wire everything so once the utility comes out, all they have to do is connect up the new lines to the new meter pan and decommission (remove) the old meter pan.  Of course, I'd like to have power until that happens.  So, is it permissible for me to connect my existing 200A meter-main's output (breaker-protected) lugs to the *utility side* of my 400A meter pan, which then will break it out on the load-side to the dual 200 load panels?  I'd short the meter socket with a couple meter jumpers.

[image]

PS - Is the following setup considered "very short" in terms of the wires connecting from the unfused meter lugs to the breakers of the new panels?

Comment: I think it would be very difficult for anyone to answer your "very short" question, as we don't have enough details. From what I can see, it's only a few pixels and I'm _sure_ that's considered "very short". However, I'd guess that reality is more than a few pixels away, but we don't know how many. Maybe a picture of the actual installation with a tape measure for scale.